# Combine several functions with callback arguments

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose I have the following two functions.

```
def f1(f: T1 => Unit): Unit = ???
def f2(f: T2 => Unit): Unit = ???
```

I want to combine f1 and f2 to some functions f3

```
f3(f: (T1,T2) => Unit): Unit
```

I can implement it easy to such simple case

```
def f3(f: (T1,T2) => Unit) = f1 { t1 => f2 { t2 => f(t1,t2) } }
```

But is it possible to do in more generic way? If I have more than two functions with different arguments, how to combine them to make it possible to call with `f: (T1,T2,...,TN) => Unit` callback?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Can you show an actual use case?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably going to be overkill, but you could do something like this using shapeless.

We can represent a couple of side effecting callback functions as an `HList` :

```
import shapeless._

type Callback[A] = (A => Unit) => Unit

def f1(f: Int => Unit): Unit = f{ println("f1"); 5 }
val f2: Callback[String] = f => f{ println("f2"); "foo" }

val callbacks = f1 _ :: f2 :: HNil
// Callback[Int] :: Callback[String] :: HNil
```

Now we want to turn this last `HList` into a function which takes an `(Int, String) => Unit` as argument.

First we will introduce a type class `OneCallback` which can turn an `HList` like `callbacks` into one callback taking an `HList` as an argument (consisting all the different arguments of the multiple functions). For `callbacks` we will get a `Callback[Int :: String :: HNil]`.

```
trait OneCallback[F, Args] {
  def apply(funs: F): Callback[Args]
}

object OneCallback {
  implicit val hnilOneCallback: OneCallback[HNil, HNil] = 
    new OneCallback[HNil, HNil] {
      def apply(funs: HNil): Callback[HNil] = callback => callback(HNil)
    }

  implicit def hconsCallback[A, FT <: HList, AT <: HList](implicit 
    oneCallbackTail: OneCallback[FT, AT]
  ) = new OneCallback[Callback[A] :: FT, A :: AT] {
    def apply(funs: Callback[A] :: FT): Callback[A :: AT] = 
      (f: (A :: AT) => Unit) =>
        funs.head { argH =>
          oneCallbackTail(funs.tail) { argsT =>
            f(argH :: argsT)
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Lastely we will create a function which can turn this `Callback[Int :: String :: HNil]` into a `((Int, String) => Unit) => Unit` :

```
import shapeless.ops.function.FnToProduct

def oneCallback[CS <: HList, A <: HList, C](callbacks: CS)(implicit 
  ocb: OneCallback[CS, A],
  ftp: FnToProduct.Aux[C, A => Unit]
): C => Unit = c => ocb(callbacks).apply(ftp(c))
```

Now we can combine multiple callback functions as :

```
val cb = oneCallback(f1 _ :: f2 :: HNil)
cb { (i, s) => println(s * i) }
// f1
// f2
// foofoofoofoofoo
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not particularly elegant or easy to write but I think it's easy to implement and understand

```
val f1: String => Unit = s => println(s)
val f2: Int => Unit = i => println(i)
val f3: Double => Unit = d => println(d)


implicit class Chain[A](f: A => Unit) {
  def o [B](g: B => Unit): Tuple2[A, B] => Unit =  {
    case (x, y) => f(x); g(y)
  }
}

(f1 o f2 o f3) ("a" -> 1 -> 2.0)
```

**EDIT:** This is actually better than I expected.There's not a limit of 22 parameters as everything is a nested tuple2.